# How to stop auto line-breaks and centralize the lines the way I want them to be?

Tags: html, css

How to make 
[image: this code]

look like 
[image: this one]

All I want to do is put the line-breaks in the correct place as it is in the second image. I also tried to use display options, as well as text-align...  Maybe I am doing it the wrong way.  I would be greatful if you guys could help.

```
<html>
     <head>
          <title>Tribute page</title>
          <style type="text/css">

            html,body{
              font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
              text-align:center;
              min-width:260px;
              color:#333;
            }

            #main{
              margin:30px auto;
              padding:15px;
              border:0px solid;
              border-radius:5px;
              background:#eee;
            }

            #image{
              max-width: 100%; 
              display: block; 
              height: auto;
              margin: auto;      
            }

            #img-div{
              margin:-5px;
              margin-top:20px;
              width:100%;
              border:5px solid white;
              background:white;
            }

            #img-caption{
              margin:15px;
            }

            #headline{
              margin-top:50px;
              text-align:left;
            }

            ul{
              max-width:550px;
              margin: 0 auto;
              text-align:left;
            }

            li{
              margin: 10px;
            }

            h3{

            }

            blockquote{
              font-style: italic;

            }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
         <div id="main">
            <h1 id="title">Dr Norman Borlaug</h1>
            <div>The man who saved a billion lives</div>
            <div id="img-div">

               <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Freecodecamp\Tributepage\norman.jpg" id="image">

               <div id="img-caption">Dr. Norman Borlaug, second from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</div>

          </div>

        <div id="tribute-info">
        <ul>
          <h3 id="headline">Here's a time line of Dr. Borlaug's life:</h3>
          <li><strong>1914</strong> - Born in Cresco, Iowa</li>
          <li><strong>1933</strong> - Leaves his family's farm to attend the University of Minnesota, thanks to a Depression era program known as the "National Youth Administration"</li>
          <li><strong>1935</strong> - Has to stop school and save up more money. Works in the Civilian Conservation Corps, helping starving Americans. "I saw how food changed them", he said. "All of this left scars on me."</li>
          <li><strong>1937</strong> - Finishes university and takes a job in the US Forestry Service</li>
          <li><strong>1938</strong> - Marries wife of 69 years Margret Gibson. Gets laid off due to budget cuts. Inspired by Elvin Charles Stakman, he returns to school study under Stakman, who teaches him about breeding pest-resistent plants.</li>
          <li><strong>1941</strong> - Tries to enroll in the military after the Pearl Harbor attack, but is rejected. Instead, the military asked his lab to work on waterproof glue, DDT to control malaria, disenfectants, and other applied science.</li>
          <li><strong>1942</strong> - Receives a Ph.D. in Genetics and Plant Pathology</li>
          <li><strong>1944</strong> - Rejects a 100% salary increase from Dupont, leaves behind his pregnant wife, and flies to Mexico to head a new plant pathology program. Over the next 16 years, his team breeds 6,000 different strains of disease resistent
            wheat - including different varieties for each major climate on Earth.</li>
          <li><strong>1945</strong> - Discovers a way to grown wheat twice each season, doubling wheat yields</li>
          <li><strong>1953</strong> - crosses a short, sturdy dwarf breed of wheat with a high-yeidling American breed, creating a strain that responds well to fertalizer. It goes on to provide 95% of Mexico's wheat.</li>
          <li><strong>1962</strong> - Visits Delhi and brings his high-yielding strains of wheat to the Indian subcontinent in time to help mitigate mass starvation due to a rapidly expanding population</li>
          <li><strong>1970</strong> - receives the Nobel Peace Prize</li>
          <li><strong>1983</strong> - helps seven African countries dramatically increase their maize and sorghum yields</li>
          <li><strong>1984</strong> - becomes a distinguished professor at Texas A&M University</li>
          <li><strong>2005</strong> - states "we will have to double the world food supply by 2050." Argues that genetically modified crops are the only way we can meet the demand, as we run out of arable land. Says that GM crops are not inherently dangerous
            because "we've been genetically modifying plants and animals for a long time. Long before we called it science, people were selecting the best breeds."</li>
          <li><strong>2009</strong> - dies at the age of 95.</li><br><br>

         <blockquote>
          <p>"Borlaug's life and achievement are testimony to the far-reaching contribution that one man's towering intellect, persistence and
            scientific vision can make to human peace and progress."</p>
          <div>-- Indian Prime Minister Manmohan Singh</div>
        </blockquote>

            <h3>If you have time, you should read more about this incredible human being on his <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug" target="_blank">Wikipedia entry</a>.</h3>

        </ul>

            </div>
       </div>

       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close :)
If you pull the `<blockquote>` and the `<h3>` out of the `<ul>` and insert after the `</div>`beneath it, you would have your result the way you want it.

Like this:

```
         </ul>
         </div>
         <blockquote>
          <p>"Borlaug's life and achievement are testimony to the far-reaching contribution that one man's towering intellect, persistence and
            scientific vision can make to human peace and progress."</p>
          <div>-- Indian Prime Minister Manmohan Singh</div>
        </blockquote>
        <h3>If you have time, you should read more about this incredible human being on his <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug" target="_blank">Wikipedia entry</a>.</h3>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

There are some other "rule of thumb" things wrong with your code, but like you said you are new, and I won't bother you with it :)

Welcome, and hope you like coding.

EDIT: Also, if you would like the line to break the exact same places as in your example, you can make a `<div>`around the two elements (the blockquote and the h3) and set a width on the div with CSS or add padding to the div, so that it would match exactly.

Comment: Hey, it worked just as simple. Just curious... what would be the correct width and padding?

Comment: Well, that depends on the browser and the monitor etc. like @Bryce Howitson mentioned, but if I were you I would open my html document in a browser i.e. Chrome, and right click the div you just added and find out that way. You can style the element directly in the console and then figure out the (almost) the exact pixel size you need, and then copy the styling into your own code.
Note: you only need to either add padding or a width. You can do both, but you don't need to :)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you just need to add a width or max-width to the elements attribute (in this case the `<p>` and `<div>` inside `<blockquote>`. Then you can use margin to center the element.

```
blockquote p {
    width: 600px; //this could be a percent or max-width
    margin: 0 auto; //margin top/bottom & margin left/right
}
```

One thing to note, the exact location of line breaks will vary between monitors, browsers, and devices as the "size" of the font will vary a bit. You can either fight that and try to be super exact or you can embrace the fluid nature of the web.

Comment: Yes, but, the same code that I showed in the first image is displayed the way it is(on the first image) on my computer, so I think the problem is with the code....

Comment: Sorry, the other answer is correct, there is a mistake in the position of closing tag for the `</ul>`, which forces the max-width from `<li>` to apply to the `<blockquote>`.  Yes your CSS makes it wider, but the real fix is in the code structure first.